# ApiAxle returning empty result

Tags: node.js, apiaxle

I am using API Axle for my node API.In that i am following this tutorial http://www.cubrid.org/blog/cubrid-appstools/apiaxle-open-source-api-management-analytics-proxy/.In that after i want to see how many hits for a particular API or particular keys..

For that i am using the following link:

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/v1/apis/charts
http://127.0.0.1:3000/v1/keys/charts
```

But its returning `results:{}`.PLease help me to solve this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, would love to understand why I'm not capturing statistics either.

Answer (score 1):

Phil from ApiAxle helped me figure this out. It turns out you need to run apiaxle-proxy with the -q flag, or use their separate queue processor. There is some documentation about this here: https://github.com/apiaxle/apiaxle/blob/4b1a80ef576b3af9511c1239e99841b2d521eb63/proxy/apiaxle-proxy.coffee#L533-538